# MySQL Select rows with multiple column entries

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a denormalized table, records, with columns:

biz_address, customer_name, dept_ID, order_ID, order_amount.

biz_address and customer_name have duplicate column entries.

How can I get list of all orders for addresses with more than 5 orders per address?

What I want is a result set like so...

```
+-----------------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+
| biz_address | customer_name | dept_ID  | order_ID | order_amount |
+-----------------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+
| 100   CLAY DR   | REAL      | 1     | 54    |     60 |
| 100   CLAY DR   | REAL      | 2     | 55    |      4 |
| 100   CLAY DR   | REAL      | 3     | 56    |      5 |
...
| 11    MOORE ST  | ABCO      | 10    | 67       |     7  |
| 11    MOORE ST  | ABCO      | 11    | 78       |     2  |
| 11    MOORE ST  | ABCO      | 12    | 79       |     4  |
| 11    MOORE ST  | ABCO      | 13    | 80       |     8  |
```

I know how to get a count:

```
SELECT biz_address, customer_name, order_ID, COUNT(*) 
FROM records
GROUP BY customer_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5;
```

Which returns this...

```
+----------------+------------+------------+----------+
| biz_address   | customer_name | order_ID   | COUNT(*) |
+--------+------------+---------------+----------+
| 100   CLAY DR    | REAL    | 54      |        6 |
| 11    MOORE ST   | ABC     | 67      |        8 |
```

Comment: I'm surprised your last query runs at all. I'd expect it to give an error along the lines of "SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column"

Comment: @Error_2646 mysql extends the group by to allow for this teh RDBMS is free to choose any value from the non-aggregrated  selected values.

Comment: @donethat your next step would be to use that as a WHERE EXISTS and join on the address  so `SELECT * From records B where exists (<your query alis table as A> and A.BIZ_Address = B.Biz_address)`

Comment: Do you want 5 orders per address or per customer? Your text says address, but your attempted query uses customer names.

Comment: 5+ orders per address.

Comment: @xQbert Interesting. I tried it in a fiddle before commenting to make sure I wasn't losing my mind. Looks like 5.5 + 5.6 it's allowed, but fails for later versions. But the MySQL documentation does indeed say it's permitted even in 8.

Comment: @Error_2646 it is the flag ONLY_FULL_GROUP _BY , which can be disabled or enabled

Answer (score 3):

Join your original table with a subquery that gets all the addresses with the specified number of duplicates.

```
WITH dups AS (
    SELECT biz_address
    FROM records
    GROUP BY biz_address
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
)
SELECT r.*
FROM records AS r
JOIN dups ON r.biz_address = dups.biz_address
```

Comment: I think the join should be on address per spec.  I think multiple customer_names could exist at the same address.

Comment: In their query they count duplicates by customer name.

Comment: Fair enough but the quesiton was stated, "How can I get list of all orders for addresses with more than 5 orders per address?"  so I guess it's ambigious

Comment: I know. I suspect they're equivalent -- the sample data has the same customer names for the same addresses.

Comment: I've updated the query to group and join on address.

Comment: Thank you. What is the correct question to ask in SQL? I'm not looking for a value, I'm looking for when there are more then x amount of entries in a table, and then list all those entries. I never would have looked for WITH AS as a solution on my own.

Comment: You don't need the CTE, you could do the same thing with `JOIN (SELECT ...) AS dups`.

Comment: The point is that you need to get all the addresses with duplicates, then filter the original table against this list.

Comment: @barmar well done as always ;P

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution using `COUNT()` as a window function instead of an aggregation function.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY biz_address) AS count
  FROM records
) AS t
WHERE count >= 4;
```

Window functions require MySQL 8.0 or later.